# Postgresql Encryption

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm learning how to encrypt columns in postgresql and this is my code but i am getting an error when i try to insert values into the table, also i would like to make the function encrypt the data after insert. i dont know why is the reason that this error is coming up. if you guys could help me, i will really appreciate it. its for a school project that im putting together

```
-- dummy table
CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id_num smallint NOT NULL,
    username Varchar (50)  NOT NULL,
    password Varchar (50)  ,
    test1 Varchar (50)  ,
    test2 Varchar (50)   ,
    test3 Varchar (50)  ,
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_num)
);

---encryption function 
--postgresql trigger function
CREATE FUNCTION encrypt_solution_testing_function2() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
DECLARE
BEGIN
new.username := PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT(new.username, 'sha1') ;
new.password := PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT(new.password , 'sha1');
new.test1 := PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT(new.test1  , 'sha1')  ;
new.test2:= PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT(new.test2  , 'sha1')  ;
new.test3 := PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT(new.test3 , 'sha1') ;
RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;  

--before insert trigger but would like to make it, after insert

CREATE TRIGGER encrypt_audit_log_testing2 
BEFORE INSERT ON public.users 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE  encrypt_solution_testing_function2();
```

error message:

```
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(50)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function encrypt_solution_testing_function2() line 5 at assignment
SQL state: 22001
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of the `pgp_sym_encrypt` function is not a string, but a binary string (`bytea`). So if you store the result in a string column, it will be cast to `varchar` on assignment.

Now the encrypted string can be longer than the clear text, and its string representation is more than double that size:

```
SELECT octet_length(pgp_sym_encrypt('some string', 'sha1'));

 octet_length 
══════════════
           77
(1 row)

SELECT pgp_sym_encrypt('some string', 'sha1');

                                                                       pgp_sym_encrypt                                                                        
══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 \xc30d040703020df0c213a136973962d23c014bb8a3d8e55a31ad3b64e5a389a2ae5212be75ccc570881f5d191e3f3528f0f98058bde3e30921b87a385b1ce56240e6bad20410eef10ac5a68511
(1 row)
```

So you should not use `varchar(50)`, but `bytea` to store the encrypted data.

Also note that the second argument to `pgp_sym_encrypt` is *not* a hashing algorithm, but a password:

```
SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt('\xc30d040703020df0c213a136973962d23c014bb8a3d8e55a31ad3b64e5a389a2ae5212be75ccc570881f5d191e3f3528f0f98058bde3e30921b87a385b1ce56240e6bad20410eef10ac5a68511'::bytea, 'sha1');

 pgp_sym_decrypt 
═════════════════
 some string
(1 row)
```

Everybody who knows that password can decrypt the data.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. That makes a lot of sense.